# Problem plotting a csv in whcih each line is a case of covid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I can't find a solution for this...

So I have a csv with all the COVID-19 cases in México. Each row/line of the csv is a case, starting from the first one to the last case uploaded to the data.
This csv has a lot of objects: if the test give positive or not of COVID or if the patient has obesity, smokes, etc. All of this is specified with `SI` or `NO` (yes or no) and are objects (I have another file with yes or no as `1` or `2`).
I want to plot in an histogram (or in any other kind of plot) the information referred to the comorbilites and if the case is positive or negative. I mean, how many cases that are positive have any comorbility (obesity, etc) or not. And then, have a plot between the comorbilities and dead of the patient, in order to see if there is a correlation between having tabaquism or diabities with the dead or intubation of a patient.
Problem is, that I really don't know how to do it, because the things I graph relate to dates so I can do a line plot, but when I come to this kind of plots I really don't know the way to go.
I have read a lot for doing this but I really can't find an example that related to the things I want to do... I am a non-programmer so this is always very stressful for me.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cbAf5dJhbhLjhJKX5_DuhWkyTGuKZPLI/view?usp=sharing).

A pic:

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is about plotting the distributions of these other comorbidity variables as a histogram, whilst also differentiating between those who are COVID-19 positive and COVID-19 negative.
One simple way to do this is by using seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(x = COMORBIDITY_VAR, hue = "Resultado", data = df)
```

where `df` is the pandas data frame and `COMORBIDITY_VAR` is a comorbidity variable that you input as a string into this function.